# java.lang.NullPointerException while reading specific sheet from xlsx using org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel

Tags: apache-poi, spark3, spark-excel

We are trying to read one specific sheet from Excel (.xlsx with 3 sheets) using org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel into spark dataframe.

We are using MSExcelLowFootprintParser parser.

code used is

```
    val hadoopConf = new Configuration()
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("ExcelReadingExample")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()


spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("hadoopoffice.read.lowFootprint", "true")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("hadoopoffice.read.header.read","true")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("hadoopoffice.read.sheets", "Most Runs Over - 2010")

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO")
val schema = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("col", IntegerType, nullable = true),
    StructField("col1", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("Runs", IntegerType, nullable = true),
    StructField("BF", IntegerType, nullable = true),
    StructField("SR", DoubleType, nullable = true),
    StructField("s4", IntegerType, nullable = true),
    StructField("s6", IntegerType, nullable = true),
    StructField("Against", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("Venue", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("Match Date", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("Match Time", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("Match Partition Time", StringType, nullable = true)
))

val df: Dataset[Row] = spark.read
  .format("org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel")
  .option("hadoopoffice.read.sheets", "Most Runs Over - 2010")
  .option("read.spark.simpleMode","true")
  .option("read.lowFootprint", "true")
  .option("multiLine", "true")
  .option("read.spark.simpleMode.maxInferRows","1000")
  .option("read.header.read","true")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("D:\\excel\\spark-hadoopoffice-ds-s2-ho-1.3.9\\spark-hadoopoffice-ds-s2-ho-1.3.9\\src\\resources\\MostRuns_Over2008.xlsx")

df.show();
```

We are facing exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader$SheetIterator.getSheetName(XSSFReader.java:325)
at org.zuinnote.hadoop.office.format.common.parser.msexcel.MSExcelLowFootprintParser.processOPCPackage(MSExcelLowFootprintParser.java:374)
at org.zuinnote.hadoop.office.format.common.parser.msexcel.MSExcelLowFootprintParser.parse(MSExcelLowFootprintParser.java:267)
at org.zuinnote.hadoop.office.format.common.OfficeReader.parse(OfficeReader.java:92)
at org.zuinnote.hadoop.office.format.mapreduce.AbstractSpreadSheetDocumentRecordReader.initialize(AbstractSpreadSheetDocumentRecordReader.java:138)
at org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel.HadoopFileExcelReader.<init>(HadoopFileExcelReader.scala:55)
at org.zuinnote.spark.office.excel.DefaultSource.$anonfun$buildReader$4(DefaultSource.scala:322)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:148)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(FileFormat.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:240)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:159)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:35)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:832)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
at scala.collection.Iterator$SliceIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:266)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1429)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1429)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1429)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$take$2(RDD.scala:1449)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2281)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

**Its working if i read all sheets instead of one sheet. Its also working if i dont use low foot print parser.**

- org.apache.poi version **4.1.2**
- spark-hadoopoffice-ds version **1.3.9**
- spark version **3.1.2**

Comment: [Apache POI 4.1.2 was released in early 2020](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html#4.1.2), what happens if you upgrade to the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its working if i read all sheets instead of one sheet. It is also working if i don't use low footprint parser.**

Good  observed. File a bug about this on https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/issues.

**Reason for the NullPointerException**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader$SheetIterator.getSheetName(XSSFReader.java:325)
at org.zuinnote.hadoop.office.format.common.parser.msexcel.MSExcelLowFootprintParser.processOPCPackage(MSExcelLowFootprintParser.java:374)
```

[MSExcelLowFootprintParser](https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/blob/main/fileformat/src/main/java/org/zuinnote/hadoop/office/format/common/parser/msexcel/MSExcelLowFootprintParser.java) in program line 374 calls `iter.getSheetName()` where `iter` is [XSSFReader.SheetIterator](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_2/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFReader.java?view=markup#l203). Then [XSSFReader.SheetIterator.getSheetName](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_3/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFReader.java?view=markup#l358) calls `xssfSheetRef.getName()` but the `XSSFSheetRef xssfSheetRef` will not even be set to something and will be null unless [XSSFReader.SheetIterator.next](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_2/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFReader.java?view=markup#l301) gets called.

Its working if you read all sheets instead of one sheet because then `MSExcelLowFootprintParser.java` code line 374 never gets reached because no sheet names are given. Then the first call after   `while (iter.hasNext()) {...` will be `InputStream rawSheetInputStream = iter.next();` and that calls `XSSFReader.SheetIterator.next` which sets `xssfSheetRef`.

It is also working if you don't use low footprint parser because that not uses `org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader` at all.

**Solution**

`InputStream rawSheetInputStream = iter.next();` needs get called immidatelly after  `while (iter.hasNext()) {` in `org.zuinnote.hadoop.office.format.common.parser.msexcel.MSExcelLowFootprintParser.processOPCPackage`. That will set `XSSFReader.SheetIterator.xssfSheetRef` and so avoid the NullPointerException.